# GPS Application in ARM7

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, gps, arm7

I'm developing a GPS application under Linux, with ARM7 microprocessor.

Which compiler do you recommend? Do you know if there is any toolkit with libraries ready to develop GPS applications?

A friend of mine recommended gcc... what do you guys think about it?

Thank you

Comment: Is the target running Linux or only the development machine?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the compiler matters that much. What is more important is your precise understanding of the library you are using, or of the actual device you are invoking.

However, I will recommend GCC, and I do recommend using a very recent version of GCC. For instance, GCC 4.6.2 is appearing these days, and there have been lot of work recently put in GCC to improve its perfomance for ARM processors. So, if possible, us a 4.6 GCC, not a 4.3 one  (some hardware vendors don't give recent GCC with their ARM development kit; you should consider in that case building your GCC (and perhaps binutils) from their source code.

I know nothing about GPS itself.